# Heroku build never finish

Tags: node.js, heroku

When i deply in the building, never finish.

-----> Build

```
   Running build
   > project@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_4b8ee4ef59b560044f52943cad6d37e5
   > node server.js
   Templates engine started!
   Db started!
   App listening on port 8000!
```

After .listen the process never finish.

Never finish build, after one hour time limit exceded.

`const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000; app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log('App listening on port ${PORT}!'); });`

***In heroku local is works***, but when i push to ***heroku master***, build never finish :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxAaO.png

I connect with await to mongose for db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `package.json` under `scripts` -> `build` you are telling it to run your project `node server.js` (this should only be your `start` script) instead of telling it to **build** your project.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "start"
  }     true :)